# Why documentation says release is 11.04 instead of 10.10

Tags: versions, yelp

I went to the desktop menu and opened `System`->`About Ubuntu` to read more. It says *You are using Ubuntu 11.04* when I am using 10.10. Why is that so?

Update: This has been fixed!

Comment: Same for me :-/

Comment: haha yeah. Same for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- It's a bug.
- Run `lsb_release -a` in terminal, and it will show you the correct version that you are using.
- Here is a bug **[report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yelp/+bug/690654)**.

Answer (score 2):

Eat your heart out:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs/+bug/690248

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-translations/+bug/695734

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10273445

There you go. Right answer hehe. Nice question hehe.

UPDATE - The "bug" has been fixed.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs/+bug/690248

As of 1 of February 2011

Answer (score 1):

Known bug -- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yelp/+bug/690654