# About Ubuntu shows wrong release

Tags: 10.10, 11.04, versions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does documentation tell me I am running 11.04 when it is 10.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19639/why-does-documentation-tell-me-i-am-running-11-04-when-it-is-10-10)

Hi,

I recently reinstalled my computer from a freshly downloaded CD. I did not select at any time to get an experimental version or beta. But right after the installation (and updating) `System -> About Ubuntu` tells me that:

> You are using Ubuntu 11.04 - the Natty Narwhal - released in April 2011 and supported until October 2012.

Why is that so?

When I check `Software Sources` there are no pre-released updated enabled or other channels.

Is this jut a Bug in `About Ubuntu` or am I really running 10.04.

I got some sound, graphics and application issues, so I'm wondering if this could be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are searching is this: [Why documentation says release is 11.04 instead of 10.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19639/why-does-documentation-tell-me-i-am-running-11-04-when-it-is-10-10)

Comment: When items are duplicates please flag or vote to close as duplicate instead of posting an answer.