# How can I convert audio from ogg to mp3?

Tags: sound

I'm looking for a well working audio converter which is able to convert audio files (ogg) to mp3 format. I tried it with the "sound converter" from the software center but it stopped converting after 6 of 12 files.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I use `ffmpeg` for sound conversion:

```bash
ffmpeg -i file.ogg file.mp3
ffmpeg -i file.{ogg,mp3}      # if only the extension changes
```

If your filename contains spaces, don’t forget to [quote](https://askubuntu.com/a/984802/507051) it, e.g.:

```bash
ffmpeg -i "file with spaces".{ogg,mp3}
```

To perform batch processing, you can either use a `for` loop like

```bash
for i in *.ogg; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp3"; done
```

or – especially for many and/or large files! – [GNU `parallel`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/parallel):

```bash
parallel ffmpeg -i "{}" "{.}.mp3" ::: *.ogg
```

This last command will convert every `.ogg` file in the current directory to `.mp3` efficiently using your CPU(s) to perform multiple tasks in parallel.

To set the audio bitrate, `ffmpeg` provides the `-b:a BITRATE` option, e.g. `-b:a 192k`.
If you want to include metadata like title, album and so on, you can use these options:

```bash
-map_metadata 0:s:0 -id3v2_version 3 -write_id3v1 1
```

See [`man ffmpeg`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ffmpeg.1.html) and [this linuxforums.org.uk post](https://web.archive.org/web/20210622194452/https://linuxforums.org.uk/index.php?topic=9836.msg102913;PHPSESSID=r38ed2dvu5ksqnlbg4fnlqjij5#msg102913) for further information.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I found this S.O. question more helpful for mapping metadata: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52354427

Answer (score 11):

You can try **ogg2mp3**.

You can install `ogg2mp3` in Ubuntu 12.04 or 13.10 by first getting
the debian package file from this [ogg2mp3 download
page](http://code.google.com/p/ogg2mp3/downloads/list).

Open the .deb file using the `Software Center`, it will install it for you.

### Batch conversion

First put all the files that you want convert into a single folder (let’s
call it `ogg_src`). Then simply give `ogg2mp3` the folder path with the
appropriate audio parameters (bitrate, channels etc) and it will
automatically convert one by one, open a terminal and type:

```
ogg2mp3 /home/me/ogg_src/ -a 96
```

For more information please read its manual (including the actual converting tool called `lame` by using the below commands:

```
man ogg2mp3
man lame
```

[Source](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/01/command-line-batch-ogg-to-mp3-converter-ubuntu-linux/)

Answer (score 8):

SoundConverter, which makes use of GUI(Gnome), but can also be used from the command line. Supported Formats *Mp3, OGG, AAC, WAV, Flac*

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install soundconverter
```

Convert:

```
soundconverter -b -m "mp3" -s ".mp3" /home/za/Music/blackmill.ogg
```

- b, --batch Convert  in  batch mode, from command line, without a graphical user interface.
- m, --mime-type Set the output MIME type for batch mode.  The default is audio/x-vorbis.
- s, --suffix Set the output filename suffix for batch mode.  The default is .ogg.

Answer (score 5):

I use [WinFF](http://code.google.com/p/winff/wiki/UbuntuInstallation) which is a fast AV converter, and it has a friendly interface. Very easy to use once you familiarize yourself with the presets that come together with this app. If you're interested in audio file coversion only, you can use WinFF's audio presets, and convert multiple files at once with great speed and best quality.

You can install WinFF from the Software Center, or with Synaptic or you can use the link provided above to install the latest stable version. You need to install prior to installing WinFF the following packages: ffmpeg and libavcodec-extra-53 or libavcodec53.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the script i use to convert ogg to mp3 with id3 tags.

Save this text below to a file called `ogg2mp3`. Make it executable with `chmod +x ogg2mp3`.

Execute in terminal and pass one parameter, which is the path to a folder.

(you need ffmpeg obviously, and zenity package for notifications)

```
#!/bin/bash
#

kbps=320

crtpath=$PWD
cd "$1"

old_IFS=${IFS}
IFS='
'

files=$(find . -type f -regex '^.+\.ogg$' | sort)

declare -i nn=0
for file in ${files}
do
  fn=$(readlink -f "$file")

  dest=$(echo "$fn"|sed -e 's/\.ogg$/\.mp3/')

  ffmpeg -i "$fn" -ab ${kbps}k -map_metadata 0:s:0 "${dest}"

  let nn=nn+1
done

cd "${crtpath}"
zenity --info --text "Finished converting ogg to mp3.${IFS}Processed ${nn} files."
#notify-send -i info Information "Finished converting ogg to mp3.${IFS}Processed ${nn} files."

IFS=${old_IFS}
```