# Convert many music files to mp3

Tags: music, mp3, convert

Is it possible to convert many music files(directory and sub-directories) to mp3? There are more then a thousand songs there I would like to convert, but I would also like to keep folder structure. If that's not possible, I could convert folder by folder. Any solutions? I searched some posts, but the solutions are old, and software used is not supported anymore. Thanks!

Edit1:  Sound Converter works, but leaves some sort of rustling.

Comment: You can use [Soundconverter](http://soundconverter.org/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert music between formats and keep its metadata?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11116/how-do-i-convert-music-between-formats-and-keep-its-metadata)

Comment: There is always internet sites

Comment: @Find Me In The Woods Which sites?

Comment: You can always test the output of converted files. If you use various formats over a thousand of files than of course you will test first not to end up with a loss of library.

Comment: I have the same problem on mp3 and ogg

Comment: zamar.com
online-convert.com

I just google it!

Comment: simple but true

Comment: No, these convert one file at the time. I need to convert many files.

Answer (score 1):

Well lets Start Over With my answer. While Soundconverter was previously suggested by VBR....What is the primary extension of the souund files you are trying to convert, how many do you have and o you need options like variable bit rate, meta taggin etc etc

Comment: I suggest expanding this answer with more information about specifically how to install and use this utility to mass-convert audio files to mp3.

Comment: I hear a lot of humming. Any solution?